# How to send API requests from an array sequentially

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

**The situation**:
I have an API which is connected to a DynamoDB database via Lambda. Each request performs changes on several records in the database. Hence it is required that each request is fully completed before the next request can be send to the API. Otherwise I will get inconsistent data accross the database.

**Where I need help:** Given I have an array of elements to request in the database...

```
const requestArray = [123, 456, 567]
```

... and my code works with an await of the API post method promise ...

```
async function databaseRequestExample (requestArray[x]){

     const result = await postAPIFunction(requestArray[x])

}
```

... I would like to know how to **work through the array one request after the other**. So **concurrent** invocation via **array.map** is **not an option**.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [async.eachSeries](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#everySeries) function of the `async` library.

Basically it'll run the `foreach` loop for you but run it serially. So you can fire your requests one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to save all the incoming requests to a FIFO SQS queue in order. Then, you can let the lambda function pull from the queue one request at a time, and set the reserved concurrency of the lambda function to 1. This will ensure that at any given time there is at most one lambda function is querying/making changes to the DynamoDB, and it's processing in order.